# What do I write to Slack's Socket-Mode websocket endpoint to send a chat message using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, websocket, slack, slack-api

I am trying to write a simple Slack chatbot for my team using Ruby. It's a bit rough because Slack doesn't have official support for Ruby. Nevertheless, I've been able to open a websocket and listen to Slack events using this code I wrote:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "async"
require "async/io/stream"
require "async/http/endpoint"
require "async/websocket/client"
require "excon"
require "json"

module Slack
  class Client
    Error = Class.new(StandardError)
    AquisitionError = Class.new(Error)
    ConnectionError = Class.new(Error)

    CONNECTION_AQUISITION_ENDPOINT = "https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open"

    def initialize
      @token = "my-app-token"
    end

    def connect
      connection_info = Excon.post(CONNECTION_AQUISITION_ENDPOINT, headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization:  "Bearer #{@token}",
      })

      result = JSON.parse(connection_info.body)

      raise(AquisitionError) unless result["ok"] # better error later

      websocket = Async::HTTP::Endpoint.parse(result["url"])

      Async do |_task|
        Async::WebSocket::Client.connect(websocket) do |connection|
          payload = connection.read

          raise(ConnectionError) unless connection_check(payload)

          puts "Listening..."
          handle(payload) while (payload = connection.read)
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def connection_check(payload)
      payload[:type] == "hello"
    end

    def handle(payload)
      puts payload.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

The documentation leads me to believe that I can write JSON to this `connection` e.g.

```rb
connection.write({
  # JSON to send a message in Slack here
  # Probably need to specify the channel somehow
  # Probably need to specify if I'm using markdown
  # Have no idea what the form should be
})
```

But I haven't been able to figure out what form that JSON needs to take.

Comment: Not to rain on your good efforts, but maybe you want to take a peek at this: https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client

Comment: I've looked at that, but it seems to be using a different, older API, e.g. `rtm.start` is no longer supported: https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also running into this and trying to determine why the docs do not provide a clear answer. It appears that you do not infact send requests back over websockets, and instead use websockets only to accept requests.

Which would mean that you would use something like the webAPI to perform responsive actions, you can see this pattern in the [PythonSDK with websockets example provided by Slack](https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/socket-mode/index.html).

eg:

```
if req.type == "events_api":
  # Acknowledge the request, this ack is sent back over websockets
  # the format is: { 'envelope_id': req['envelope_id'] }
  response = SocketModeResponse(envelope_id=req.envelope_id)
  client.send_socket_mode_response(response)

  # Add a reaction to the message if it's a new message
  # notice that this request uses the web_client here and not the socket one
  if req.payload["event"]["type"] == "message" \
     and req.payload["event"].get("subtype") is None:
     client.web_client.reactions_add(
       name="eyes",
       channel=req.payload["event"]["channel"],
       timestamp=req.payload["event"]["ts"],
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. It supports the same conclusion that I came to, that I write acknowledgements for events to the websocket, but I have to go through the web API to perform actions.